# I am getting "missing keyword" error in co-related sub query in Oracle

Tags: oracle

```
EXPLAIN SELECT S.ITEMID, X.STATUS
FROM
(select itemid,itemdescription from A WHERE parent_itemid IN(SELECT ITEMID FROM A WHERE itemtype='CT') AND itemtype='SK' AND id='02') S,
(select  s1.itemid from s1,s2 where s1.itemid=s2.itemid and status='RC' )  X
where S.itemid=X.itemid
```

Comment: https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/how-do-i-display-and-read-the-execution-plans-for-a-sql-statement

Comment: There is no *correlated* subquery in your query. [Edit] the question and provide a [example], at least the `CREATE` statements of the tables. And you should consider switching to explicit `JOIN` syntax and qualify all columns with the table aliases.

Comment: You aren't returning x.status from your 'X' sub query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not *correlated subquery* that makes problems, but syntax. Not just `explain`, but `explain plan for`.

I don't have your tables so I used Scott's (properly joined):

```
SQL> explain plan for select s.dname, x.ename
  2  from (select d.deptno,
  3               d.dname
  4        from dept d
  5        where d.deptno in (select b.deptno
  6                           from dept b
  7                           where b.deptno = 10
  8                          )
  9       ) s join
 10       (select e.deptno,
 11               e.ename
 12        from emp e
 13        where e.deptno = 10
 14       ) x
 15    on s.deptno = x.deptno;

Explained.

SQL>
```

---

In your case, presuming that everything else is correct,

```
explain plan for select s.itemid, x.status
from (select a.itemid,
             a.itemdescription 
      from a 
      where a.parent_itemid in (select b.itemid 
                                from a b 
                                where b.itemtype = 'CT'
                               ) 
        and a.itemtype = 'SK' 
        and a.id = '02'
     ) s join
     (select s1.itemid 
      from s1 join s2  on s1.itemid = s2.itemid 
      where s1.status = 'RC'         --> which table does STATUS belong to?
     )  x
  on s.itemid = x.itemid;
```

I'd also suggest you to always use table aliases because it is not clear what belongs to which table. For example, `status = 'RC'` - without alias, it is impossible to know which table has it. If both, you'd have *ambiguity*.

Finally, write formatted queries. Mess you posted is difficult to read and understand. Most modern GUI tools have built-in formatters; I suggest you use it. Or, use one of online formatters. Or, format it manually. Just try not to do what you're doing now.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for [`EXPLAIN`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/ex_plan.htm#i17492) is:

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
SELECT...
```

Also in the 2nd subquery you must select the column `status` because you want to select it in the outer `select`:

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
SELECT S.ITEMID, X.STATUS
FROM
(select itemid,itemdescription from A WHERE parent_itemid IN(SELECT ITEMID FROM A WHERE itemtype='CT') AND itemtype='SK' AND id='02') S,
(select  s1.itemid, status from s1,s2 where s1.itemid=s2.itemid and status='RC' )  X
where S.itemid=X.itemid
```

Also `status` should be qualified by the table's name just to avoid any ambiguities.